# Pass comma-separated array as function argument

Tags: arrays, excel

I have a column containing unique identifiers, and another containing prices:

```
A | B
--+---
1 | $2
2 | $4
3 | $1
s | $6
7 | $5
x | $4
5 | $4
```

Somewhere else in the workbook I also have a column containing comma-separated arrays:

```
    C
---------
2,3,s
3,1
x
7,2,3,s,5
```

In D column I want to have the sums of the respective prices, e.g. `2,3,s` in C1 would give `$11` in D1. ($4 + $1 + $6 = $11)

I have tried this formula searching through the array `{2;3;"s"}`:

```
=SUM(SUMIF($A$1:$A$7;{2;3;"s"};$B$1:$B$7))
```

but it only works with a hardcoded array. This doesn't work:

```
=SUM(SUMIF($A$1:$A$7;C1       ;$B$1:$B$7))
```

What should I change in this function so that it would properly read the textual comma-separated arrays?

(A user-defined function that accomplishes this quickly would be appreciated as well.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT with a SEARCH():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1:$A$7,C1))*$B$1:$B$7)
```

This will iterate through Column A and see if the value is included in the string in C1.  SUMPRODUCT sums the values in B where the SEARCH returns true.

[image]

---

If your column A will contains things like `a` and `aa` or `1` and `11` both will be picked up.  To ensure that the correct one is picked up we can change the formula a little and force the specific lookup:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("," & $A$1:$A$7 & ",","," & C1 & ","))*$B$1:$B$7)
```

Comment: Truly awesome. The latter formula is working perfectly.